# Attaching a document to an email that's been sent as part of a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365

I was wondering if it's at all possible to attach a document to an email that is sent as part of a workflow?

I've managed to create a workflow to email users to let them know when their phone is ready for collection but I was wondering if I could get a document attached to that email or if I'm dreaming too big?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Kindly have a look at this link, http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you know if this add in will work with Sharepoint Designer 2013?